# How to prevent App from crashing when wifi connection is lost

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, android-wifi

Looked for a lot of suggestions, but couldn't find one which would fit for me.

> I'm executing web service call:

```
/**
 * Making service call
 */
private String makeWebServiceCall(String urlAddress, int requestMethod, String params) {
    String response = "";
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try {
        urlConnection = getConnection(urlAddress, requestMethod);
        urlConnection.connect();
        writeParameters(urlConnection, params);
        response = convertStreamToString(urlConnection);
        Log.d("makeWebServiceCall : ", response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //response = "Failed to connect";
        Log.d("makeWebServiceCall ", response);
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException parsing to json", e);
    }
        return response;
}

private HttpURLConnection getConnection(String urlAddress, int requestMethod) throws IOException {


    URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        if (requestMethod == POST) {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } else if (requestMethod == GET) {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.launcher_logo)
                .setTitle("No internet connection")
                .setMessage("Please turn on mobile data");
    }

    return urlConnection;
}

private String writeParameters(HttpURLConnection connection, String jsonString) throws IOException {

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonString)) {

        OutputStream outputstream = connection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream, "UTF-8"));

        bufferedWriter.write(jsonString);

        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputstream.close();

        return jsonString;

    } else {
        return "JSONString is empty";
    }
}

private String convertStreamToString(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    String responseLine = "";

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String line;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            responseLine += line;
        }
    }
    return responseLine;
}
```

When connection is lost I get exception "IOException parsing to json":

> logcat:
>
> E/RestClient: IOException parsing to json
>                                                  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.1 (port 80) after 3000ms
>                                                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
>                                                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
>                                                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
>                                                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
>                                                      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:67)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
>                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
>                                                      at com.example.pc.teltonikaapplication.JSon.RestClient.makeWebServiceCall(RestClient.java:118)
>                                                      at com.example.pc.teltonikaapplication.JSon.RestClient.deviceDownloadUploadData(RestClient.java:73)
>                                                      at com.example.pc.teltonikaapplication.fragment.MainWindowFragment.doInBackground(MainWindowFragment.java:107)
>                                                      at com.example.pc.teltonikaapplication.fragment.MainWindowFragment.doInBackground(MainWindowFragment.java:28)
>                                                      at com.example.pc.teltonikaapplication.util.Task.doInBackground(Task.java:27)
>                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Everything seems OK, if there is no connection Exception is caught, but how to handle crashing from preventing it?

Comment: use a broadcast receiver to check when you are connected to internet or not

Comment: Use a local database and save some data which is needed to make the app run even in offline. If there is no internet connection available display the local stored data in your application.

Answer (score 3):

Once I had implemented a check in my app, to see if there is any internet connection or not. You can have a look at this --

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context cont){
this.context = cont;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (connectivity != null)
{
NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
if (info != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

}
 return false;
}
}
```

You can initialize an object of this class in your `OnCreate` method.

And finally call this class' method just before you upload files.

```
Boolean isInternetConnected = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
if (isInternetConnected)
{
    //perform your job here.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is good But imagine that when swift execute this method the internet connection is ok but when enter the method for that the internet connection lost some thing like Json getting